# NullReferenceException on trying to use my first user-defined type

Tags: c#, arrays, nullreferenceexception

What I'm trying to do is define my own type that contains 2 `int`s to use in a 2-dimensional array. The application for this is using the array indexes as x,y coordinates for objects in 2-d space to be displayed. So object with data stored at `array[13,5]` would be displayed at x=13,y=5, and the properties of that object could be retrieved with `array[13,5].property1`, for example. The type I've defined is extremely simple:

```
chunkBlocks.cs:
public class chunkBlocks {
    public int blockType;
    public int isLoaded;
}
```

then, I initialize the array:

```
chunkBlocks[,] _bData = new chunkBlocks[17, 17];
```

This all compiles/runs without error. The NRE is thrown when I try to assign a value to one of the properties of the type. For debugging, I have the code written as:

```
_bData[i, n].blockType = 5;
```

and the NRE is thrown specifically on the `.blockType` portion. I've tried changing the type to initialize with 0 values for both `int`s to no avail:

```
public class chunkBlocks {
    public int blockType = 0;
    public int isLoaded = 0;
}
```

I've Googled around and searched SO, and I've not been able to turn up anything. I'm sure it's a relatively simple matter, but I'm not experienced enough to be able to pinpoint it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialize every instance of the array:

```
_bData[i, n] = new chunkBlocks();
```

Now assign the value to it:

```
_bData[i, n].blockType = 5;
```

You will have to initialize every instance, you just have declared them in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this:

```
for(int i = 0;i<17;i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 17; j++)
    {
         _bData[i, j] = new chunkBlocks ();
    }
}
```